# Linux 64b, problems with libXinerama.so.1

Tags: linux, 64-bit, libraries

I am trying to run an example for the Leap Motion..

I have installed the 64b driver, but I got

```
elect@elect-desktop:~/Downloads/LeapDeveloperKit/Examples/FingerVisualizer$ ./FingerVisualizer 
./FingerVisualizer: error while loading shared libraries: libXinerama.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

so I added it to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and now I get

```
elect@elect-desktop:~/Downloads/LeapDeveloperKit/Examples/FingerVisualizer$ ./FingerVisualizer 
./FingerVisualizer: error while loading shared libraries: libXinerama.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

An ldd returns this

```
elect@elect-desktop:~/Downloads/LeapDeveloperKit/Examples/FingerVisualizer$ ldd FingerVisualizer
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf770a000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib32/libGL.so.1 (0xf75e6000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf74b0000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf749d000)
libXinerama.so.1 => not found
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf7498000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xf73f9000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf73dd000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf73d4000)
libGLU.so.1 => not found
libLeap.so => /home/elect/Downloads/LeapDeveloperKit/Examples/FingerVisualizer/./../../LeapSDK/lib/x86/libLeap.so (0xf7145000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf705c000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7018000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf6ffb000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf6e47000)
libnvidia-tls.so.331.20 => /usr/lib32/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.331.20 (0xf6e43000)
libnvidia-glcore.so.331.20 => /usr/lib32/libnvidia-glcore.so.331.20 (0xf4c00000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf4bde000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf770b000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf4bc4000)
libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0xf4b79000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf4b75000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf4b6d000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and tried to include

`/home/elect/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1`

It works

Answer (score 2):

Just do

```
apt install libxinerama1
```